# Having a template parameter depend on a parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, using

I have defined the class

```
template <typename... Ts> struct Bar {
   using inner_type = /* whatever */;
};
```

Now, I need to define a templated class `Foo` whose template parameters are some parameter pack, and a value of type `Bar::inner_type` instantiated for that parameter pack. Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to do it. If I define it this way:

```
template <Bar<Ts...>::inner_type SomeValue, typename... Ts> struct Foo { };
```

the compiler doesn't recognize `Ts` when it's used, since it hasn't see the parameter pack yet; but if I define it this way:

```
template <typename... Ts, Bar<Ts...>::inner_type SomeValue> struct Foo { };
```

the compiler sneers at my attempt to use a parameter pack before other template parameters.

So how can I do this?

Note: In case it matters, this failed for me with GCC 4.9.3.

Comment: a non-type template parameter (e.g. `template <int I>`) ?

Comment: Can't you use `template <typename T, T t> struct Foo;` ?

Comment: the best thing would be to show us how you intend to instantiate Foo

Comment: @bolov: I can't show you that, since I can't declare it... but what's so special about its instantiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partially specialize your struct:

```
template<typename...>
struct Bar { using inner_type = int; };

template <typename T, typename T::inner_type T>
struct Foo;

template <typename... Ts, typename Bar<Ts...>::inner_type SomeValue>
struct Foo<Bar<Ts...>, SomeValue> { };

int main() {
    Foo<Bar<int>, 3> foo;
}
```

This way `Ts` parameter pack is deduced and `Foo` expects the second template parameter to be of type `Bar<Ts...>::inner_type`.

Comment: This should not compile... it has a parameter pack before another template parameter.

Comment: @einpoklum It is deduced in a specialization, it's legal. It compiles indeed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I could come up with:

```
template <class Inner, Inner Val, class... Args>
struct Foo {
  static_assert(std::is_same<Inner, typename Bar<Args...>::inner_type>::value, "Wrong type");
};
```

You need to explicitly name the type.

Comment: This is what I've been doing as a workaround. (Actually in my case I don't bother with the static assert since I use that value as an argument to a function which needs `Bar<...>::inner_type`). I might end up accepting this but I can't upvote it since I don't like it... :-P

Answer (score 0):

does this solve the issue?

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename... Ts> class Bar {
 public:
    using inner_type = int;
};

template <typename... Ts> class Foo {
  using bar_inner_type = typename Bar<Ts...>::inner_type;
  static_assert(is_same<int, bar_inner_type>::value,"");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can do something like this:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct Bar {
   using inner_type = /* whatever */;
};

template <typename... Ts> struct Foo {
   using inner_type = typename Bar<Ts...>::inner_type;
};
```

Comment: No, you did not. I need to pass a value as a template parameter, not the type. See the accepted answer.